# Totem not playing certain videos in 12.04

Tags: totem

The videos that work properly in 10.04 are not working in 12.04.

```
haris@psycho:~/music$ file Captain\ Tsubasa\ 2\ NES\ -\ 21\ -\ Coimbra_s\ Theme.mp4 
Captain Tsubasa 2 NES - 21 - Coimbra_s Theme.mp4: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2

haris@psycho:~/music$ file Captain\ Tsubasa\ 2\ Nes\ Music\ -\ 01\ Opening.mp4 
Captain Tsubasa 2 Nes Music - 01 Opening.mp4: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2

haris@psycho:~/music$ file Batman\ \(NES\)\ Music\ -\ Continue\ Theme.mp4 
Batman (NES) Music - Continue Theme.mp4: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2

haris@psycho:~/music$ file Starship\ -\ Nothing_s\ Gonna\ Stop\ us\ Now\ \(Mannequin\)\ LYRICS.mp4 
Starship - Nothing_s Gonna Stop us Now (Mannequin) LYRICS.mp4: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
```

The third and fourth videos are not even being played by Totem while for the second one, I can hear the audio but can't see the video. The first one plays well enough. Once again, all these videos work without any problems in 10.04.

Should I report this as a bug or can it be rectified?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**For 12.04**

Until the bug is fixed & atm there is no movement towards doing so we've tracked this down to a plugin in `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad`, specifically `libgstvideoparsersbad.so`

So if desired you can move that plugin to a .bak & it should clear up decoding issues caused by this bug

For 64 bit install

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoparsersbad.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoparsersbad.so.bak
```

For 32 bit install

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoparsersbad.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstvideoparsersbad.so.bak
```

What, if any, loss of function is unclear here, I've seen none Yet, obviously the hope is this bug will be addressed in 12.04, current report - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer0.10/+bug/973014

The best self fix until bug is resolved is to patch & rebuild the bad plugins source. A quick howto here - http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12118375&postcount=6

Comment: I removed totem and made VLC my default. The above solution maybe useful for those who use totem and/or have problems while seeing file properties in nautilus for certain videos (including mp4) as addressed here: http://askubuntu.com/q/177202/78407

Comment: just to note. this issue affects -  totem, banshee, gnome-sushi, minitube, transmageddon, in some cases the totem-mozilla plugin & while haven't tried  likely parole

Answer (score 1):

you might not be having the codecs in 12.04 which you ahd in 10.04 so first you should try installing the right codec and see
try rhis to install all codecs `sudo aptitude install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: I tried installing ubuntu-restricted-extras, but the problem still persists.

Comment: then there might be a bug in totem . you could try installing vlc from the repository and see.it vlc works then there has to be a bug

Comment: Yup, vlc is beautifully playing all the videos. I'll report this as a bug.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer0.10/+bug/989663

Comment: great work!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that you can try.

Install only these:

```
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

And uninstall `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad`.

Answer (score 0):

i would add the medibuntu repositories. Which adds a ton of nice to have media codecs for your distribution.

The instruction can be found here:

http://medibuntu.org/repository.php

Comment: I tried adding it and installing the codecs. But the problem still persists. vlc played the files perfectly though. So I guess its a bug in totem.

Comment: If you do file a bug about Totem in 12.04 not playing .mp4 files, please post the bug reference here so that others can visit it and "star" it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug with `totem`.

I have managed to solve it with this:

```
mv ~/.gstreamer-0.10/registry*.bin ~/.gstreamer-0.10/registry*.bin.org
```

[I got it from here.](http://tagavalgal.blogspot.com/2011/11/quicktime-demuxer-not-found-in-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the particular `libgstvideoparsersbad.so`, you could uninstall `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` and install `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse` (from the multiverse repository as the name suggests).

(I had the same problem with totem -> some MP4 files played, others not at all.)

Comment: Has nothing to do with the multiverse plugin which only adds encoding support. Better to either patch & rebuild the bad plugin or just remove the currently borked parser plugin as mentioned. The actual decoding is done thru the gstreamer ffmpeg plugin but the parser & other  bad plugins do have value &are deps on some apps.

Answer (score 0):

I just install this package and work for me

```
   sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

and remove this

```
  sudo apt-get remove gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
```